# 404 error on Flask (cPanel). 3 refreshes needed

Tags: flask, cpanel

I'm setting up a new flask web app hosted on a python app on cPanel, everything working but each time I send a command or i refresh the page or a new function runs the 404 error appears. If i refresh the page 3 times starts working again.

I tried to change the settings of Flask, but nothing is working.

Comment: I had a similar problem where only the root URL would work and all other routes returned 404.

Add the following to the top of your .htaccess file:

`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteRule ^http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE]`

Got this info from: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63971427/10122266]

Answer (score 0):

something on your script of sessions is missing. You can either redeploy and see if it is solved. Or check the log file if the system is giving any warning or errors. In case you are not sure how to check log file then follow the steps in this tutorial. 
[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RKN3kVKCG4&t=0m21s)

Comment: Link only answers tend to get deleted.